# SQL Where statement isn't working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made some queries before and this one must be the easiest but I can't find the mistake I am making. I want in the where statement only to be searched for ATTRIBUUT = 'BVM'. The problem is that it shows me every ATTRIBUUT and not only 'BVM'.

```
select *
from bla join bla1 on KEY_NUMMER = KEY_NUMMER1
where DATUM_EINDE_REGISTRATIE is null
and nvl(DATUM_TOT,'31-12-9999') > sysdate
and ATTRIBUUT = 'BVM'
and IDENTIFICATIE in ( 123, 456 )
```

Can somebody help me what I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: I'm assuming `ATTRIBUUT` is a part of the `bla` table?

Comment: You can try bla.KEY_NUMBER = bla1.KEY_NUMMER1. Similarly, bla.ATTRIBUUT = 'BVM' or blah1.ATTRIBUUT = 'BVM'

Comment: Adam Yes, ATTRIBUUT is part of bla. @achang27 I am trying it out right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Alias's on your tables. If there is ATTRIBUUT column in both tables this could bring you unwanted results. So for example:

```
select *
from bla as A
join bla1 as B
on B.KEY_NUMMER = A.KEY_NUMMER1
where A.DATUM_EINDE_REGISTRATIE is null
and nvl(DATUM_TOT,'31-12-9999') > sysdate
and A.ATTRIBUUT = 'BVM'
and A.IDENTIFICATIE in ( 123, 456 )
```